# How to append content of 2 commands into 1 console

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My program need to run 2 commands. The second command will be run based on the result of previous command.

I was suggested and use IStreamListener() to get result of first command and check condition to run second command but the output separate into 2 console output

My code here

```
String[] cmdLine = buildCommandLine(configuration, true);
Process process = DebugPlugin.exec(cmdLine, null, null);
IProcess newProcess = DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, process, "", null);

IStreamsProxy streamsProxy = newProcess.getStreamsProxy();
IStreamMonitor streamMonitor = streamsProxy.getOutputStreamMonitor();

isProcessSuccess = true;
streamMonitor.addListener(new IStreamListener() {

    @Override
    public void streamAppended(String text, IStreamMonitor monitor) {
        if (text.contains("[ERROR]")) {
            isProcessSuccess = false;
        }
    }
} );

if (isProcessSuccess) {
    String[] cmdLine2 = buildCommandLine(configuration, false);
    Process process2 = DebugPlugin.exec(cmdLine2, null, null);
    IProcess newProcess2 = DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, process2, "", null);
}
```

How to append content of 2 commands into 1 console?

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: @Andy: I want result of the second command will be output into first command console. It will help me easy to review result because I will launch many configurations and each configuration will contain 2 command above